# How to revoke app authorization in Django OAuth Toolkit?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm implementing the OAuth2 provider with Django Rest Framework and [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit).

Django OAuth Toolkit already has a set of views for managing OAuth Applications. This view lets third-party application developers do basic CRUD on an Application model. There's also [a sample view](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/1c21410c9e4f52619a93e7d71ad4f06ef9917c1c/oauth2_provider/templates/oauth2_provider/authorize.html) for a resource owner to authorize the third-party app.

However, I can't figure out a proper way for the resource owner to revoke the third-party app authorization. There's a revoke-token endpoint but if I get it right it serves a different job.

Essentially I try to build a view similar to GitHub's "Authorized applications" page:

[image]

It looks like the [RefreshToken model](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/339f151f4cd130e6256f5747b94d64a12ee927c3/oauth2_provider/models.py#L227) is the one I should use to list the connections. But works not as expected when the user reauthorizes the app. The RefreshToken instance is created after each successful authorization prompt and the connection list grows with duplicates.

Has anyone successfully implemented a similar view with the Django OAuth Toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.. token.revoke() method is not seem to be working for refresh token one.. so i used token.delete() which completely deletes tokens from database.. I am new to oauth system, but i hope just deleting token is enough for terminate that login. if so, here is my view to delete that, u can try yourself too..

```
@login_required
def revoke_token(request, token_key):
    try:
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=token_key, user=request.user)
        refresh_token = RefreshToken.objects.filter(access_token=access_token).first()

        access_token.delete()
        if refresh_token:
            refresh_token.delete()

        messages.success(request, "Session terminated successfully.")
    except AccessToken.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "Session not found.")
    
    return redirect('sessions')
```